# R returns an error for contrast coding in R

Tags: r

I was setting contrasts for my variables (2 var; each var has two levels) by using the following code:

```
contrasts(data$Factor1) = cbind(c(0.5,-0.5))
```

It then said *Error in

```
 `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(0.5, -0.5)) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows*
```

I first thought it might be because the data was unbalanced as some data were treated as outliers and deleted before I applied contrast coding. However, even when I applied contrast coding to the unfiltered data, I saw the same error.

I appreciate people's help!

Comment: This works for me: `x<-factor(rep(1:2, each=5)); contrasts(x) <- cbind(c(0.5, -0.5))`. Are you sure there are just 2 levels? Did you check `nlevels()`? It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your help! As I checked, I did have two more unused levels which have 0 elements. I used the subset function to extract one set of data from a larger set. In the larger set, there are 4 levels. I thought after subsetting, those two levels would disappear. I found a solution, droplevels(data)$variable. Thanks again for your response!